# Saving an opening a file defaulting to location on C drive

Tags: qgis

I utilize QGIS on a few VMs in a cloud environment. We create the users profile on a separate drive that is not on the OS partition (C). We make the OS partition inaccessible to the end user (no permissions to write to it). When opening or trying to save a file, QGIS is defaulting to a location on the C: drive, which I would prefer to be documents or a different drive despite the user not having access to this location (C). Is there a way to configure this in QGIS? Also, if there is, will this configuration capture during an imaging process?

Comment: I think you could simply create a .bat file that first changes dir to your preference and then launches the executable.